# Regression similar to BWW-ANOVA

Tags: regression

I've run a 2*2*2 Mixed ANOVA with one between subjects (Group: HighScore/LowScore) and 2 Within Subjects factors (Factor1 and Factor2)

All Factors have 2 levels.

I'd now like to run something similar but a regression as I'd like to look at the Scores on a continuum rather than split by High/Low.

What would this kind of analysis be called?

Comment: A mixed model? The type would be analysis of covariance (ANCOVA), but in my opinion there is no real advantage of differentiating betweeen ANOVA, ANCOVA and linear regression, since they are equivalent.

Comment: Relevant paper here: quantpsy.org/pubs/preacher_curran_bauer_2006.pdf. I wrote an R function based on some of those equations here: https://github.com/markhwhiteii/mscelns/blob/master/R/mlm_ss.R